# Is TensorFlow.js viable for basic image recognition?

Tags: image-recognition, neural-network

So I need to create a basic image recognition AI (/neural network) for a school project and looked into TensorFlow.js a little. However, a lot of people told me it's unfit for what I'm trying to do but also couldn't help me since I can't use Python, etc. 
Does anyone know a good tutorial to get started?

If not, I tried following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab) and it works, but whenever I reload the page all the progress the network made in recognizing / classifying hand gestures for example is gone and I have to start from scratch. Is there any way to save the progress?